# How to run two NUnit console runners in parallel for the same application?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, parallel-processing, nunit-console

how can I run the NUnit console.exe in parallel for the same application. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: yes i like to do using command lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically single instance of nunit-console run tests in parallel using different threads, you can disable this by passing `/nothread` command line argument.

**EDIT**: Mode details about discussion in chart

So ratty have two tests DLLs and want to run tests for both DLLs in parallel, I suggested to create a new solution which includes both underlying projects and simply run unit tests for newly created solution, NUNit console will run tests in parallel by default

Comment: can you please explain little bit elaborate?

Comment: When you are launching unit tests using nunit-console it uses multiple threads to execute tests in parallel

Comment: To run from console just specify nunit-console.exe "path to solution file"

Comment: when starts execute two console at a time one gets terminated

Comment: I've created batch file run.cmd with single command which executes nunit-console.exe with path, and ran it twice, all working fine. NUnit 2.5.10

Comment: @sllev let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2360/discussion-between-ratty-and-sllev)